Overriding default hover, disabled, pressed (...) states on customised Flutter's FilterChip widget
I'm trying to change the default hover behaviour of FilterChip.
I tried to use MaterialStateProperty on side and shape properties to check MaterialState and react on that (meaning changing the border side from 1 to 10).
I want to keep the widget stateless.
For now, I don't want to wrap the widget with MouseRegion, GestureDetect or similar, as I think it should be possible to access and modify the default FilterChip
properties (?).
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyChip extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;

  const MyChip({
    required this.label,
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FilterChip(
      label: Text(label),
      shape: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<OutlinedBorder>((states) {
        if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
          return RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            side: const BorderSide(width: 10),
          );
        } else {
          return RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            side: const BorderSide(width: 1),
          );
        }
      }).resolve({}),
      onSelected: (bool isSelected) {},
    );
  }
}

The issue is the state is always empty and I don't know why. I thought that maybe I can't use the MaterialStateProperty on shape so I tried on side, but the result is the same (state is empty).
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      side: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<BorderSide>((states) {
        if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
          return const BorderSide(width: 10);
        }
        return const BorderSide(width: 4);
      }).resolve(<MaterialState>{}),
    ),


Any input helping me to understand the reasons is welcomed.
I tried that also on ActionChip - but it behaves the same, with no state value.
I'm on Flutter 3.19.3 so I can't use WidgetStateProperty (but at least for now it should behave as the MaterialStateProperty).
